# How to get higher paying software developer job

Tags: software-industry, salary

I work at a position where the pay is pretty average, actually pretty low for the number of years I've been out of college.  The software development process is pretty informal e.g. we don't use git/code review and any sort of agile or whatever methodology.

How do I get a higher paying software job, is it just simply apply to jobs and interview?  Should I be studying some of these technology like agile or git on my own time?  Should I be studying on company time useful skills?

Comment: Train yourself for the job you want to have

Comment: In many places "years out of college" doesn't matter much. It's more about your skill level, quality of deliverables, soft skills and, to some extent, years of "relevant experience"

Answer (score 1):

> ...is it just simply apply to jobs and interview? Should I be studying
> some of these technology like agile or git on my own time? Should I be
> studying on company time useful skills?

Yes for the first question, yes for the second question, and yes/no for the third question. In other words, yes, you should be studying, but asking us if you should be studying on company time is kind of missing the point.

Company time is for getting things done. And getting things done does involve reading documentation on company time, which you'll be required to do very frequently, but I wouldn't exactly call it "studying".

For instance, if you don't even have version control set up, you're making your current company lose money every time you're making a mistake (whether they realize it or not). That's unacceptable. It's paramount you read the "Getting Started" documentation and install a version control system as soon as you can. And yes, you should do all of this on company time.

But at the same time, if you're completely clueless about git or github, and if it's going to take you a week to understand it before you can even start using it. Then in that case, you should be doing that research on your personal time. Because honestly, you should know this stuff already. Now, I understand if an intern or a brand new junior developer doesn't know this stuff yet, but if you've been working as a software developer for the last couple of years, in your case, you have no excuse.

And as to studying agile/SCRUM methodologies, since you're doing this primarily for your own interest and for the interests of your future employers, I think you should study those topics on your own time.

Comment: not everyone can just "set up git" on their own; often that is something a company has to decide to use and set up for all employees.